# Подключена ли сетевая или нет?

Tags: ubuntu

В терминале на команду **lspci |grep Ethernet** 
Получил ответ **00:07.0 Bridge: nVidia Corporation MCP61 Ethernet (rev a2)**
При чем **Ethernet** Выделено красным. Так и не понял вообще работает она ли нет? (работает то она это понятно. Но какая именно модель?

Вот еще. Может ли кто подксзать какой тут драйвер искать?

```
 *-bridge
          description: Ethernet interface
          product: MCP61 Ethernet
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 7
          bus info: pci@0000:00:07.0
          logical name: eth0
          version: a2
          serial: 1c:6f:65:fe:f9:16
          size: 100000000
          capacity: 1000000000
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: bridge bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
          configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=forcedeth driverversion=0.64 duplex=half latency=0 maxlatency=20 mingnt=1 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
          resources: irq:41 memory:fe02d000-fe02dfff ioport:f000(size=8)
```

Команда lspci

```
russia@russia-comp:~$ lspci
00:00.0 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation MCP61 LPC Bridge (rev a1)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: nVidia Corporation MCP61 LPC Bridge (rev a2)
00:01.1 SMBus: nVidia Corporation MCP61 SMBus (rev a2)
00:01.2 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation MCP61 Memory Controller (rev a2)
00:02.0 USB Controller: nVidia Corporation MCP61 USB Controller (rev a3)
00:02.1 USB Controller: nVidia Corporation MCP61 USB Controller (rev a3)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: nVidia Corporation MCP61 PCI bridge (rev a1)
00:05.0 Audio device: nVidia Corporation MCP61 High Definition Audio (rev a2)
00:07.0 Bridge: nVidia Corporation MCP61 Ethernet (rev a2)
00:08.0 IDE interface: nVidia Corporation MCP61 SATA Controller (rev a2)
00:08.1 IDE interface: nVidia Corporation MCP61 SATA Controller (rev a2)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: nVidia Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation [GeForce GT 440] (rev a1)
02:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 1):

красным это выделено, потому что это grep это выделил. Смотрите в окрестности, там должно быть что то вида xxxx:xxxx. А по этому уже ищите.

Хотя почему думать, это просто nVidia чипсет со встроенной сетевой (у меня на ноуте такая же). В федоре все подхватывается и работает без дополнительных "драйверов".

Посмотрите список сетевых устройств командой `ifconfig -all`. Там и видно будет, кто работает, а кто нет.

Comment: Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a40:0101 TERMINUS TECHNOLOGY INC. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04d9:1702 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. Optical Mouse M90


Но гугл ничего существенного не выдает к сожалению

Comment: Вы точно выложили вывод lspci, а не lsusb?

Comment: lspci привел результат в основном вопросе

Comment: должно работать с коробки (http://hardware4linux.info/component/23510/)

Comment: Расстреляйте меня но не могу скачать (не прослеживаю где тут Download или что то подобное

Comment: так там и не будет его. Эта ссылка говорит, что ядро умеет работать с этим оборудованием. Скорее всего у Вас либо уже работает, либо очень старое ядро, либо ядро собрано ручками.
смотрите по выводу dmesg и ifconfig.